# WinGHCi always throws an exception when loading a file

Tags: haskell, ghci

When using WinGHCi to load a *.hs file, an exception is always thrown. Can anyone help me out?

Details:
*Prelude> :l qsort.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( qsort.hs, interpreted )
*** Exception: CreateDirectory ".": permission denied (Access is denied.)*

Answer (score 3):

It is solved. qsort.hs is in d:\ . Now, I move it to current user's directory, it can be loaded successfully. 
Anyway, why WinGHCi cannot access d:\? it is still a question.

Comment: Well the D drive is generally used for system recovery files and stuff like that, so perhaps normal users don't have permission to access it. Try running WinGHCi as administrator, and see if it can access the D drive then.